# Trying to install create-react-app on Mac fails

Tags: macos, node-modules, create-react-app, fsevents

I'm trying to create my first React app, and following Facebook tutorial it seems very simple, but it's failing in my Mac.

This is my environment, it seems that it fulfills the requirements:

```
Environment Info:

System:
  OS: macOS 10.14.3
  CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4558U CPU @ 2.80GHz
Binaries:
  Node: 12.0.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
  Yarn: 1.15.2 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
  npm: 6.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
Browsers:
  Chrome: 73.0.3683.103
  Firefox: 66.0.3
  Safari: 12.0.3
npmPackages:
  react: Not Found
  react-dom: Not Found
  react-scripts: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
  create-react-app: Not Found
```

But when I run the first command it fails with these errors:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
npx: instaló 91 en 4.374s

Creating a new React app in /Users/gachapin/sampleReact/my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

yarn add v1.15.2
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.6.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@*".
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/parser@1.6.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@*".
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree@1.6.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@*".
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.10.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
warning Error running install script for optional dependency: "/Users/gachapin/sampleReact/my-app/node_modules/fsevents: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node install
Arguments: 
Directory: /Users/gachapin/sampleReact/my-app/node_modules/fsevents
Output:
node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.12.0
node-pre-gyp info using node@12.0.0 | darwin | x64
node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp info check checked for \"/Users/gachapin/sampleReact/my-app/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node\" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.8/fse-v1.2.8-node-v72-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 404 https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.8/fse-v1.2.8-node-v72-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.8/fse-v1.2.8-node-v72-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.2.8 and node@12.0.0 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.8/fse-v1.2.8-node-v72-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@12.0.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info ok 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@12.0.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/gachapin/sampleReact/my-app/node_modules/fsevents/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/gachapin/sampleReact/my-app/node_modules/fsevents',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info ok 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@12.0.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
../fsevents.cc:43:32: error: no template named 'Handle' in namespace 'v8'
    static void Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports);
                           ~~~~^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:89:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagNone\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagNone));
          ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8.h:3358:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8config.h:322:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:90:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagMustScanSubDirs\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagMustScanSubDirs));
          ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8.h:3358:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8config.h:322:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:91:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagUserDropped\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagUserDropped));
          ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8.h:3358:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8config.h:322:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:92:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagKernelDropped\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagKernelDropped));
          ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8.h:3358:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8config.h:322:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:93:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagEventIdsWrapped\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagEventIdsWrapped));
          ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8.h:3358:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8config.h:322:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:94:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagHistoryDone\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagHistoryDone));
          ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8.h:3358:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8config.h:322:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:95:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagRootChanged\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagRootChanged));
          ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8.h:3358:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8config.h:322:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:96:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagMount\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagMount));
          ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8.h:3358:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8config.h:322:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:97:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagUnmount\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagUnmount));
          ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8.h:3358:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8config.h:322:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:98:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemCreated\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemCreated));
          ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8.h:3358:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8config.h:322:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:99:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemRemoved\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemRemoved));
          ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8.h:3358:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8config.h:322:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:100:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemInodeMetaMod\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemInodeMetaMod));
          ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8.h:3358:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8config.h:322:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:101:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemRenamed\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemRenamed));
          ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8.h:3358:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8config.h:322:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:102:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemModified\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemModified));
          ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8.h:3358:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8config.h:322:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:103:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemFinderInfoMod\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemFinderInfoMod));
          ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8.h:3358:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8config.h:322:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:104:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemChangeOwner\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemChangeOwner));
          ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8.h:3358:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8config.h:322:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:105:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemXattrMod\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemXattrMod));
          ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8.h:3358:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8config.h:322:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:106:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemIsFile\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemIsFile));
          ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8.h:3358:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8config.h:322:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:107:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemIsDir\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemIsDir));
          ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8.h:3358:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8config.h:322:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:73:
../src/constants.cc:108:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemIsSymlink\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagItemIsSymlink));
          ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8.h:3358:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/gachapin/.node-gyp/12.0.0/include/node/v8config.h:322:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
                            ^
../fsevents.cc:76:16: error: variable has incomplete type 'void'
void FSEvents::Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports) {
               ^
../fsevents.cc:76:31: error: no member named 'Handle' in namespace 'v8'
void FSEvents::Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports) {
                          ~~~~^
../fsevents.cc:76:48: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
void FSEvents::Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports) {
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~^
../fsevents.cc:76:50: error: use of undeclared identifier 'exports'
void FSEvents::Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports) {
                                                 ^
../fsevents.cc:76:58: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
void FSEvents::Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports) {
                                                         ^
                                                         ;
20 warnings and 6 errors generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:256:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0
gyp ERR! command \"/usr/local/bin/node\" \"/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js\" \"build\" \"--fallback-to-build\" \"--module=/Users/gachapin/sampleReact/my-app/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node\" \"--module_name=fse\" \"--module_path=/Users/gachapin/sampleReact/my-app/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64\" \"--napi_version=4\" \"--node_abi_napi=napi\" \"--napi_build_version=0\" \"--node_napi_label=node-v72\"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/gachapin/sampleReact/my-app/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v12.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/gachapin/sampleReact/my-app/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/gachapin/sampleReact/my-app/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64 --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/gachapin/sampleReact/my-app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1000:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.2.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command \"/usr/local/bin/node\" \"/Users/gachapin/sampleReact/my-app/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp\" \"install\" \"--fallback-to-build\"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/gachapin/sampleReact/my-app/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.0.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/gachapin/sampleReact/my-app/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Users/gachapin/sampleReact/my-app/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64 --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)"
info This module is OPTIONAL, you can safely ignore this error
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 19 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
├─ react-dom@16.8.6
├─ react-scripts@3.0.0
└─ react@16.8.6
info All dependencies
├─ @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.4.0
├─ @babel/plugin-proposal-decorators@7.4.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-flow-strip-types@7.4.0
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-runtime@7.4.3
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-typescript@7.4.0
├─ @babel/preset-typescript@7.3.3
├─ babel-plugin-macros@2.5.1
├─ babel-plugin-named-asset-import@0.3.2
├─ babel-preset-react-app@8.0.0
├─ confusing-browser-globals@1.0.7
├─ eslint-config-react-app@4.0.0
├─ fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin@1.0.1
├─ inquirer@6.2.2
├─ react-app-polyfill@1.0.0
├─ react-dev-utils@9.0.0
├─ react-dom@16.8.6
├─ react-error-overlay@5.1.5
├─ react-scripts@3.0.0
└─ react@16.8.6
✨  Done in 20.14s.

Initialized a git repository.

Success! Created my-app at /Users/gachapin/sampleReact/my-app
Inside that directory, you can run several commands:

  yarn start
    Starts the development server.

  yarn build
    Bundles the app into static files for production.

  yarn test
    Starts the test runner.

  yarn eject
    Removes this tool and copies build dependencies, configuration files
    and scripts into the app directory. If you do this, you can’t go back!

We suggest that you begin by typing:

  cd my-app
  yarn start

Happy hacking!
```

Although this says "Success! Created my-app", if I run yarn start it fails and http://localhost:3000/ shows an error.

Looking at the errors it seems that there is a problem installing fsevents but I have no idea of why that's happening.

What am I missing?

Comment: fsevents install is failing. There are lots of things to try here: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/3926 or https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5962

Comment: Thank you very much @DCTID. After reading your links I've donwgraded nodeJS to version 10.15.3 and now everything is working OK.